# PSCP Access Denied even with -pw option

Tags: powershell, putty

I am trying to send files from local to remote using Putty's PSCP command using powershell.

`pscp -pw somepassword D:\path\to\file.xlsx user@server123:/path/to/remote/directory`

However, I get an "Access Denied" message followed by a prompt to enter the user's password. After entering the password, the file transfer works. I need to find a way to not have to manually enter the password every time as this is supposed to be an automation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that `somepassword` has characters considered as special by PowerShell, so you first receive Access Denied because the password is incorrect. In this case try to use the following two commands:

```
$mypassword = 'somepassword'

pscp -pw $mypassword 'D:\path\to\file.xlsx' 'user@server123:/path/to/remote/directory'
```

Note that [single quotes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_quoting_rules?view=powershell-7.3) are used around the password, paths and the URL.

Then I think that it makes sense to remove the `$mypassword` variable using the `Remove-Variable mypassword` command.

PS Perhaps `pscp -pw 'somepassword' 'D:\path\to\file.xlsx' 'user@server123:/path/to/remote/directory'` will also work for you.